# An easy riddle made easier if you jot it down

Tags: riddle

```
I'll rob the desert, blunt an edge,
take a message and deliver it.

I'll fly a little with some help,
I'll even cover the cost.

I'll tell you lies and teach you well,
and even clean up after you.
```

What am I?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you

> paper?

I'll rob the desert, blunt an edge,

> Sandpaper would need sand from the desert, and is used to soften sharp edges.

take a message and deliver it.

> A message written on paper, delivered in a paper envelope.

I'll fly a little with some help,

> Folded into a paper airplane, it could fly quite nicely.

I'll even cover the cost.

> As in paper money (which is not actually paper, usually.)

I'll tell you lies

> Something fake can be described as "paper"; e.g., paper towns.

and teach you well,

> Like an academic paper, a thesis.

and even clean up after you.

> Paper towels are used for cleaning.

Comment: It is.  Well done.  The first line about the desert and the edge is all one clue.  There could be more to the message and delivery or lies and teaching lines.  The "Cost" part is sort of correct but although the name is used, in this case the material is actually not!

Comment: Hmm, okie doke. I'll see what I can do...

Comment: @MikeM Damn it I had the word paper in my mind but couldn't figure out the desert clue!! But nice job though

Comment: @MikeM. The lies part could be that strategically in a war, one can print false information and ensure that the enemy receives it, teaching them lies.

Comment: @AditKirtani Yeah, sandpaper was the last one I got. I was thinking paper towns for the lies. We'll see if I'm any closer. Still not sure about message and deliver, yet.

Comment: @MikeM. maybe something about pigeons flying around delivering them?

Comment: Any closer, @BrentHackers?

Comment: I didn't expect a revision as your original explanations were fine.  I was thinking of 'money' actually.  I just meant that it is the answer in name only, because it's usually made from something else.  I'd also say 'message and delivery' was closer before (I was hinting at what you would put your answer in).

Comment: Oh, OK, I think I get the money thing, 'cause it's not actually paper, most of the time; you just wanted "paper money". Still gotta think about the message and delivery. It's not just "paper envelope", is it?

Comment: @MikeM. It is.  And that's a pretty perfect set of explanations now. :)